# Bash find/replace and run command on matching group

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I'm trying to do a dynamic find/replace where a matching group from the find gets manipulated in the replace.

testfile:

```
…
other text
base64_encode_SOMEPATH_ something
other(stuff)
text base64_encode_SOMEOTHERPATH_
…
```

Something like this:

```
sed -i "" -e "s/(base64_encode_(.*)_)/cat MATCH | base64/g" testfile
```

Which would output something like:

```
…
other text
U09NRVNUUklORwo= something
other(stuff)
text U09NRU9USEVSU1RSSU5HCg==
…
```

Comment: I don't believe `sed` can do this. `awk` and `perl` can though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated per your new requirement. Now using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() for convenience:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*)base64_encode_([^_]+)_(.*)/,arr) {
      cmd = "base64 <<<" arr[2]
      if ( (cmd | getline rslt) > 0) {
          $0 = arr[1] rslt arr[3]
      }
      close(cmd)
  } 1' file
…
other text
U09NRVNUUklORwo= something
other(stuff)
text U09NRU9USEVSU1RSSU5HCg==
…
```

Make sure you read and understand http://awk.info/?tip/getline if you're going to use `getline`.

If you can't install GNU awk (but you really, REALLY would benefit from having it so do try) then something like this would work with any modern awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/base64_encode_[^_]+_/) {
      arr[1] = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
      arr[2] = arr[3] = substr($0,RSTART+length("base64_encode_"))
      sub(/_.*$/,"",arr[2])
      sub(/^[^_]+_/,"",arr[3])

      cmd = "base64 <<<" arr[2]
      if ( (cmd | getline rslt) > 0) {
          $0 = arr[1] rslt arr[3]
      }
      close(cmd)
  } 1' file
```

I say "something like" because you might need to tweak the substr() and/or sub() args if they're slightly off, I haven't tested it.

Comment: The `base64_encode_` isn't always at the beginning of the line, (updated question). I'm guessing I could just remove the `^`s from the regex?

Comment: odd, my previous response was deleted be someone. Anyway - no, because you need to save the part before `base64_encode_` not delete it, and Ive updated my answer to match your new requirements.

Comment: Ed, I'm seeing this error when I try to run that on my file: ```awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
         >>> match($0,/(.*)base64_encode_([^_]+)_(.*)/, <<<
awk: bailing out at source line 1```

Comment: You are using old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris). Install GNU awk and use that instead. I also added a version that'd work for nawk or /usr/xpg4/bin/awk, the 2 non-broken Solaris awks, but do try to get GNU awk as it has a ton of VERY useful additional features.

Comment: Ah, that was it. One more question for you, Ed. If I wanted to use the matched string as a file path and `cat` the file contents into `base64`, how could I do that before the `cmd = "base64 <<<" arr[2]` line?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Wouldn't you replace that `cmd=...` line instead of doing something before it? This sounds like a different question that'd benefit from it's own clear sample input and expected output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66598/discussion-between-adamyonk-and-ed-morton).

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '!/^base64_encode_/ { print } /^base64_encode_/ { fflush(); /^base64_encode_/ { fflush(); sub("^base64_encode_", ""); sub("_$", ""); cmd = "base64" ; print $0 | cmd; close(cmd); }' testfile > testfile.out
```

This says to print non-matching lines unaltered.

Matching lines get altered with the `awk` function `sub()` to extract the string to be encoded, which is then piped to the `base64` command, which prints the result to stdout.

The `fflush` call is needed so that all the previous output from `awk` has been flushed before the `base64` output appears, ensuring lines aren't re-ordered.

**Edit**:

As pointed out in the comment, testing every line twice for matching a pattern and non-matching the same pattern isn't very good. This single action handles all lines:

```
{
  if ($0 !~ "base64_encode_")
  {
    print;
    next;
  }
  fflush();
  sub("^.*base64_encode_", "");
  sub("_$", "");
  cmd = "base64";
  print $0 | cmd;
  close(cmd);
}
```

Comment: gawk only because of `gensub` I believe.

Comment: The `base64_encode_` isn't always at the beginning of the line, (updated question). I'm guessing I could just remove the `^`s from the regex?

Comment: @adamyonk, yes, and change the first `sub()` to remove `^.*base64_encode`

Comment: @EdMorton, another good point, I've added an alternative (which also handles `base64_encode` not being at the start of the line, but will need some adjustment to handle trailing text after the text to be encoded)